# Gem 'whenever' in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, whenever

I try to send message automatically by using whenever gem. I am in initial step. I install the gem 'whenever'. I done the following step.
1. Add "gem 'whenever', :require => false" to the gemfile.
2. bundle install.
3.  wheneverize .
4. in schedule.rb add the following code,

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log" 
#every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
every 5.minutes do    
   runner "Payment.sendMessage", :environment => "development"
end
```

5.And model likes,

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def sendMessage
    puts"Hello"
  end
end
```

6. When I use bundle exec whenever, I get like the following issue as

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c     
'cd /home/prabha/rails_job && bundle exec bin/    
         rails runner -e development '\''Payment.sendMessage'\'' >>     
/home/prabha/rails_job/log/cron.log 2>&1'
## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax;  
 your  crontab file was not updated.
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
```

I am stuck with this step. what I want to do the further proceed? Anyone guide me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update you crontab file.

Do the following -

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

For more information, please check whenever gem's [Github ReadMe page](https://github.com/javan/whenever#the-whenever-command).

Comment: I run this command. It shows Crontab file updated. When I again run  bundle exec whenever, it gets the same error. Is that the correct process which was followed by me ?

Comment: I just tested your code.
That message - your  crontab file was not updated. - is just a message.

I just ran your code, CRON is updated.
Check your CRON list by - `crontab -l`

You will be able to see that your CRON is updated.

Answer (score 0):

1) sendMessage should be a class method.
2) You can use "whenever" command in your project directory to see the cron configuration and then copy into your crontab.

Comment: Jindai, I change my Payment.rb def sendMessage into def self.sendMessage